# Client - Server Notification independent application / web independent

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications, notifications

I'm searching for a technology to send server-side notifications to .Net and web applications (in case of server restarts at example).

Those notifications should be sent and received at runtime. I'm searching for existing technologies, no services like one-signal or something like that, because I need to implement it myself for a project.

I do prefer .Net and Asp.Net, but I'll be fine with Node at example too; does someone have a few recommendations for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a good use case for signalr.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2